# Decomposition of a simplicial complex into pseudo-manifolds

Tags: simplicial-complexes

Is a result of the following type known:
Any finite simplicial complex of dimension $d$ may be, up to collapsing, covered by (not necessarily induced) subcomplexes that are pseudo-manifolds, in the sense that all d-dimensional simplicies are covered.

For example, in dimension 1 the result would be "any graph is covered by cycles up to collapsing vertecies of degree 1".